# Changing the background color of a radio button with tkinter in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, colors, tkinter, radio-button, ttk

I added a few radio buttons to a GUI I'm working on in Python 3 using ttk, but there is a white square around them which doesn't match the blue background of the rest of the GUI.

I've tried `background= ...`, `foreground= ...`, `bg= ...`, `fg= ...`, and a few other things in  `ttk.Radiobutton()`. It works fine with labels and other things... what am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ttk doesn't support arguments such as "background", "foreground", "font" on its Radiobutton, but it does support styles.
Example code (python 3.4):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


root = Tk()                         # Main window
myColor = '#40E0D0'                 # Its a light blue color
root.configure(bg=myColor)          # Setting color of main window to myColor

s = ttk.Style()                     # Creating style element
s.configure('Wild.TRadiobutton',    # First argument is the name of style. Needs to end with: .TRadiobutton
        background=myColor,         # Setting background to our specified color above
        foreground='black')         # You can define colors like this also

rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(text = "works :)", style = 'Wild.TRadiobutton')       # Linking style with the button

rb1.pack()                          # Placing Radiobutton

root.mainloop()                     # Beginning loop
```